# How to make sympy acknowledge that 0/0 is a division by zero

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to make sympy evaluate the expression x/x at the value x = 0 in such a way that it raises an exception or returns NaN.

For example, the following code:

```
x = sympy.Symbol("x")
expr = (x/x).subs({x:0}).evalf()
print(expr)
```

returns a 1.  This is simply false.  It is true that the limit of x/x as x approaches zero is 1, but in terms of its actual value at x = 0, it is undefined.  I want sympy to raise a Division by Zero exception or return NaN, which is the mathematically correct answer.

In fact, the problem exists already before I substitute x = 0:

```
x = sympy.Symbol("x")
expr = x/x
print(expr)
```

Returns a 1.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: I thought that `with evaluate(False): expr = x/x; val = expr.subs(x, 0)` might do it but `val.evalf()` is zero and `val` is `0*1/0`. This is disturbing.

Comment: I tried `(1/x).subs({'x':0})` and ended up in the zoo.

Comment: @wim Right. By default x is allowed to be complex. 1/0 in the complex plane is understood as complex infinity, denoted `zoo` in SymPy (where `oo` looks like infinity and z is traditional notation for a complex variable.)

Comment: Says who? I've never heard of 1/0 being understood as complex infinity. It's just undefined.

Comment: @wim https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero#Riemann_sphere

Comment: That is not the complex plane, though. It literally says ℂ ∪ {∞}, i.e. a new point has been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed, the issue is that `x/x` evaluates to 1 immediately, so a subsequent substitution of x by 0 is not really happening.

A way to avoid evaluation is to pass evaluate=False flag to the product of x with 1/x:

```
>>> expr = Mul(x, 1/x, evaluate=False)
>>> expr
x/x
>>> expr.subs(x, 0)
nan
```

The result is "Not A Number", meaning this does not evaluate to a number.

(In SymPy, all division is multiplication by reciprocal quantity: there are Add, Mul, Pow but no Div or Sub).

Comment: The operator `/` hooks into more or less the same expression, without the `evaluate=False` in [`sympy.core.expr.py:Symbol.__truediv__`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/d68f2996b04ab7aa214c05d8a1ae86a83ac43cc4/sympy/core/expr.py#L177).  This early implicit evaluation is more or less a crappy bug in SymPy, imo, they shouldn't do that.